# c# WPF How user control-codebehind intercat to MainWindow-codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a c# WPF project with following files:
-MainWindow.xaml.cs, -MainWindow.xaml, -Login.xaml.cs, -Login.xaml. pufferview.xaml

in the Login.xaml i createt a login interface with userid and password. On the passwordbox i have _Keydown event in my Login.xaml.cs to check if userid and password are correct. If true i want to call a function in my my MainWindow.xaml.cs.

Like in my example:

```
   public void LoginOK()
        {
            login1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            pufferview1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
  <StackPanel>
        <local:Login x:Name="login1"></local:Login>
        <local:PufferView x:Name="pufferview1" Visibility="Collapsed"></local:PufferView>
    </StackPanel>
```

That will change the whole content of the MainWindow from the login usercontrol to the pufferview user control.

But i cant figure out how to connect from my login.xaml.cs to my Maindow.xaml.cs

Here also the Login _KeyDown function if it helps:

```
 public void passwordbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                if (useridbox.Text == "user" && passwordbox.Password == "123")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("success");
                    MainWindow.LoginOk(); // <- THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
                }
                else
                {
                    //messagebox falsches Passwort
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't do that. It creates a dependency between MainWindow and UserControl. Use MVVM and keep CodeBehind as empty as you possibly can. (And do not save passwords in cleartext ...)

Comment: Application.Current.MainWindow.LoginOK();

Comment: @Fildor yes i think that was what i am looking for! i will check some videos how MVVM works. thanks. ... And yes that password there was just to figure stuff out...